# Polygon Overlay completed event is getting triggered when clicking on the same point twice before a valid polygon is drawn

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are using Google Map's drawing manager to draw polygon. When user has mistakenly clicked the same point twice before a valid polygon is drawn, overlayCompleted event is getting triggered. Is there a way to trigger the overlayCompleted event only after a valid polygon is drawn?

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({

    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON]
    }
  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {

  console.log('overlay complete');
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=drawing">
</script>
```

Please refer the fiddle that we have created. On selecting polygon and clicking on same point twice, is calling the overlaycompleted event.

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ae7v8uzb/)

Comment: AFAIK you can't turn this "auto-complete" feature off. I don't think there is any way to know that the Polygon was auto-completed in the `overlaycomplete` event. And you don't have access to the map click events when the drawing manager is in use (which could help). I think this can be pretty annoying depending on the use case, so I'd suggest that you open a new issue in their request tracker... oh wait you have done that already... [Issue 146361228](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146361228).